# flutter cloud firbase not shoing any add information

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
Future<void> updatedonner() async {
  try {
    final CollectionReference cartItemsFirebase =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("cartitem");

    for (List<String> item in itemspages) {
      final data = {
        'name': item[0],
        'price': item[1],
        'image': item[2],
      };
      await cartItemsFirebase.add(data);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error uploading data to Firestore: $e");
  }
}
```